# Function behaves differently inside a package than outside

Tags: packages

I defined a function `TestHead` in a notebook as follows:

```
TestHead[z___] := TrueQ[{z} == Cases[{z}, x_ /; Head[x] === avar]]
```

to test whether a bunch of variables all have a certain head `avar`. When I do this in a notebook and define a variable `a` using

```
a /: Head[a]=avar
```

this works fine and gives `True` for `TestHead[a]`. However, when I make a package

```
BeginPackage["TestHead`"]
TestHead::usage=""
Begin["`Private`"]
TestHead[z___] := TrueQ[{z}==Cases[{z},x_/;Head[x]===avar]]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

load the package and again define a variable `a` as above, the function `TestHead` now gives `False` when acting on `a`.

Why is this and how I can remedy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `avar` is in the `` TestHead`Private` `` context. One fix is to write your package with an explicit context on `avar`, such as `` Global` ``:

```
TestHead[z___] := TrueQ[{z}==Cases[{z},x_/;Head[x]===Global`avar]]
```

You could have debugged this for instance with `Trace` and you would have seen instantly, why your `SameQ` results in `False`:

```
Trace@TestHead[a]

(*
{TestHead[a],TrueQ[{a}==Cases[{a},TestHead`Private`x_/;Head[TestHead`Private`x]
===TestHead`Private`avar]],
{{Cases[{a},TestHead`Private`x_/;Head[TestHead`Private`x]===
TestHead`Private`avar],{{Head[a],avar},avar===TestHead`Private`avar,False},{}},
{a}=={},False},TrueQ[False],False}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

The other possibility, of course, is to have `avar` be declared by the package (it will thus be under the `` TestHead` `` context, i.e. its full declaration is `` TestHead`avar ``):

```
BeginPackage["TestHead`"]
TestHead::usage = ""
avar::usage = ""
Begin["`Private`"]
TestHead[z___] := TrueQ[{z} == Cases[{z}, x_ /; Head[x] === avar]]
End[]
EndPackage[]
```